# Can I somehow import an image/screenshot of a website and then have it transform it to a XD design?

Tags: import, adobe, screenshot, adobe-xd

I'm not looking to convert a website like Protoship does.

I'd like to be able to make a screenshot of a website and then import/translate that to a XD design.

Is there a plugin or way I'd be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to make a prototype for PowerApps and now I've seen that there's literally an option to exactly what I wanted to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can by using [ProtoPie](https://www.protopie.io/adobexd) plugin.

Comment: This can transform a picture to a prototype?